# How to get the count of same data in array of object with the info about number of count

Tags: javascript, lodash

suppose I have an array of object `arr1`

`arr1 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}]`

I want the information of count having same id in array or object form.

I tried to get the info using for loop , map and Lodash.
I got the result. But want o do it in any efficient way.

My working code

```js
const arr1 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}];

const arr2 = []
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  var obj = {}
  _.keys(arr1[i]).map(o => {
    obj[o] = arr1[i][o]
    obj["count"] = arr1.filter(a => {
      return a.id === arr1[i].id
    }).length
  })
  arr2.push(obj)
}
var arr3 = _.uniqBy(arr2, "id")

console.log(arr3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.countBy(arr1, "id")`? Why not use the already existing functionality?

Comment: I can use. Actually i am used to in Lodash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the count of all items based on their `id` by using [`countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#countBy).
2. Remove duplicates with [`uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy).
3. Add the count with [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/#map).

The last two can be done [in a chained operation](https://lodash.com/docs/#lodash) which will do lazy evaluation instead of two full loops.

```js
const arr1 = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}];

const counts = _.countBy(arr1, "id");

const result = _(arr1)
  .uniqBy("id")
  .map(x => ({...x, count: counts[x.id]}))
  .value();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is working fine in snippet. But didn't worked in actual code. It returned LodashWrapper

Comment: You can explicitly unwrap the value by adding `.value()` at the end. It's usually not needed, though. I've added it to the answer, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Group by the `id`, and map the groups. Convert each group to an object that is based on the first object in the group + the length of the group as the `count`:

```js
const arr = [{name: "name1",id: 1},{name: "name2",id: 1},{name: "name3",id: 4},{name: "name3",id: 3},{name: "name1",id: 5}];

const result = _(arr)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map(group => ({ ...group[0], count: group.length }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```